# In this sentence, is changing "迎える" to "迎えられる" for a potential or honorific reason?

Tags: honorifics, potential-form

Here is part of a document that I am reading:

> 本日は、世界最高の大学のひとつで卒業式を**迎えられる**皆さんとご一緒できて、とても光栄です。

"everyone who is able to be attending" or
"everyone who is attending" as an honorific ?

Comment: It would probably be very hard to answer if I don't have the prior or latter texts since I am sorry I do not understand this Japanese alone.

Comment: @KentaroTomono ok. I have re-written the question with much more surrounding context.

Comment: Thank you.That's become perfect. Unfortunately, I got to go **right now** with apology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would undoubtedly be an honorific form, and not potential.

The sentence looks to be part of a speech by a guest at the commencement.  If the 「[迎]{むか}えられる」 part were meant to be a potential form, it simply would not be polite enough for the occasion and therefore, highly unnatural for the context.

Notice the 「ご」 in 「ご一緒」, for instance.  These public speeches are generally formed in a very polite and formal style even when the speaker is a few times older than the graduating students.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeess.+1 Coundn't have enough time until I answer.lol.